# PHP str_replace лимит replace параметра

Tags: php, str-replace

```
str_replace("{content}", "long text!", $subject);
```

Кто нибудь сталкивался с тем, что если во втором параметре очень большое содержимое, то код просто не работает?
В документации я не нашел никаких лимитов или ограничений.

Comment: На сколько большое? Пример? Может проблема не количестве, а в том, что, например, контент на русском?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский до 13000 символов работает, больше не хочет. Для проверки использую просто lorem...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хотя нет, в простом тесте на новом php файле все работает нормально.

Comment: работает всё https://onlinephp.io/c/a82b3

Comment: Значит что-то не так с данными....

Comment: в 7+ нет ограничений по длине, в 5 было в 2 в 32степени. ВОзможно ты сталкиваешь с ограничениями по памяти в настройках. memory_limit  По умолчанию она ограничена в 128мбайт

Comment: @Red я тоже так думал, увеличил memory_limit, не помогло. Видимо все же в коде ошибка.